# Educational software for graduate mathematics

Tags: education, math-software

Our university uses computer software to help automate and expedite the learning process for basic math classes (college algebra, trigonometry, precalculus, etc.). Software such as this provides several benefits:

- Reduced study time through calculation of ideal recall for spaced repetition
- Increased motivation by providing sense of achievement
- Immediate feedback to easily evaluated questions and basic definitions

Considering how much effort has been spent on such resources as Wolfram MathWorld, Maple, or even this website, it seems reasonable to expect such a product aimed at graduate students. After all, why write a static textbook now that computers are prevalent? **Is there software or similar interactive resources available to help streamline the learning of mathematics at the graduate level?**

Comment: @Amzoti While it's great that much of this material is available for free, it's not quite for what I was looking. I'm more interested in something centralized that provides interaction and reinforces concepts to long term memory. As an example, I started to make a website [here](http://mathoverload.net/) to address this very need, but it will never be completed because ain't nobody got time for that.

Comment: Graduate mathematics is, at least to my undergraduate eyes, an entirely different beast than undegrad/remedial math.  Graduate math seems to focus more on proofs, logical statements, etc. than on flashcard style memory.  Problems in undergraduate math are nearly universally a class $P$ problem--solvable *and* verifiable in polynomial time.  Graduate problems, however, seem to be very difficult to just verify a solution is correct...  just 2 cents on why interactive resources may not exist at the graduate level.

Comment: @anorton I agree that proof verification can be a difficult task and requiring the student to enter proofs in a computer friendly format would fail to present the casual style of most research papers. However, in spite of the potential for error in placing the onus of verification on the student, wouldn't you agree that such a method is at least as good as self study from a textbook at even its worst points, far superior at its strongest, and certainly a beneficial aid to a student in an existing program?

Comment: @user2129992, I think that Singular and Macaulay2 are good for algebraic geometry courses.